# Why Chrome history is showing files not opened with the browser

Tags: google-chrome

I was looking through my history and noticed quite a lot of `file://` entries listed. The majority of them were not downloaded files and opened using different programs. For instance: videos that I watched with MPC, text files viewed with notepad, pictures opened with Fireworks are all listed in my history. I'm not sure what to make of it and seems invasive. I don't want my Windows Explorer (not IE) history merged with my Chrome history. Am I missing something? A setting checked that should be unchecked? A rouge Extension?

Answer (score 0):

What’s likely happened is that you have some programs which use an IE component, and you have [Chrome Frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_Frame) installed.

Windows includes an IE [control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_widget) which programs can use to simplify processing or displaying web markup instead of having to create their own implementation.

Chrome Frame allows IE to use Chrome’s rendering and [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) engines *inside* IE. That way, you get the benefits of IE like the interface, bookmarks, etc. with the advantages of Chrome’s renderer and increased JavaScript speed.

The interaction of these two could result in Chrome logging file accesses in a third program.